# How to display Latitude and Longitude in a Map View (Android)?

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

> I have the Latitude and Longitude stored in the database, but how can i show it in a Map View instead of opening the coordinates every time on a browser.

> Can i display it inside the Native Android App and not redirect everytime to Google Maps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Show Maps In Your Map By Using Map Fragment Or Map Activity
first add fragment in xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

second Implement OnMapReadyCallback and override onMapReady function

```
    public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

   
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

the steps described in android developer site [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start)

Note That To Use Display Google Maps In Your App You Need API KEY You Can generate Your Key In Google Developer Console and this is [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , after you get the lat long from the firestore.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latlong);
                    markerOptions.title(latlong.latitude + " : " + latlong.longitude);
                    googleMap.clear();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlong));
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: what is latlong here ?